# [Swipe Elite Note]Camera Unable to Focus

Tags: rom-flashing, custom-roms, camera, rom, stock-rom

I have flashed a custom ROM recently on my device.Everything is working nicely except the camera.The camera used to work perfectly before flashing the ROM.Now,the camera is unable to focus.
[image: Image clicked with my device]

I think this is not a Hardware issue but a software issue.

How do I repair this bug?

My device name is Swipe Elite Note.

I will be thankful for any help!